# How I use a local variable in a SQL fiddle query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sqlfiddle

I was trying to create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/1160)

```
DECLARE @binsize INT = 5;
select 5;
select @binsize; <-- this fail.
select 6;
```

And got this error.

> Must declare the scalar variable "@binsize".

I have found sample like this and works ok in sql server.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
DECLARE @find varchar(30); 
/* Also allowed: 
DECLARE @find varchar(30) = 'Man%'; 
*/
SET @find = 'Man%'; 
SELECT p.LastName, p.FirstName, ph.PhoneNumber
FROM Person.Person AS p 
JOIN Person.PersonPhone AS ph ON p.BusinessEntityID = ph.BusinessEntityID
WHERE LastName LIKE @find;
```

**SOLVE**

Going with the GO change solve the issue.  but still open other issues.

```
DECLARE @binsize INT = 5;
select @binsize + 2 ;
select @binsize + 5 ;
GO
```

Only return 7

Comment: Get rid of the semi-colons.

Comment: Note that semicolons should be used wherever possible in supportive dialects, but yes, that is the (questionable) solution in this case. I wouldn't recommend skimping on them in T-SQL, though, as (A) that's just good ANSI, and (B) MS are on record as stating that they might become mandatory in a future release. Unlikely, but worth starting early...

Comment: or select 'go' as query terminator in the 4th combo box below the query

Comment: Using `GO` as the query terminator is a much better solution than dropping semi-colons.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, You are right is a duplicated, but the solution there doesn't work. You can check the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/43750) on the selected solution doesn't even compile.

Comment: @Juan The OP there chose the wrong answer, nothing the site can do about that; also, the fact that their sample query doesn't compile doesn't make the solution wrong (it's just not the optimal answer). In either case, the fact that the OP chose the wrong solution doesn't make the questions different (and that can be further equalized through voting, hint, hint). Your solution should be the other answer on that question, which is to change the query terminator from `;` to `GO`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I just downvote the question and I lost 1 reputation too. I dont understand how this work :(. Anyway I understand the question is duplicated. But there one answer is wrong, and the other is incomplete. The answer here was more complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AaronBertrand suggested, using `GO` is [a better practice](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)  like below:

```
DECLARE @binsize INT = 5;
select @binsize;
GO

select 5;
```

Note: In the right hand corner on **SQLFiddle** site, you will need to switch the query terminator to use `GO` keyword.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/1200/0)

Comment: While this works in this simple case, it is [not exactly a best practice](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons.aspx), and will break when the OP uses a query construct that actually *requires* semi-colons.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Good point! I actually like your idea of using GO. I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but that doesnt work for me. Im only getting one 5 instead of two. If you change `select 7` you may see the difference [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/1195)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza My apologies if I misunderstood your question. But, why are you expecting a `2` when you are clearly setting your variable to `5`?

Comment: sorry I mean a double 5. not a two. In the result only show a single 5

Comment: Oh okay. If you are expecting a 5 twice, you can just `select 5` outside your `GO` statement something like above.

Comment: @Juan SQLfiddle has a couple of limitations that I've seen, one is that it can only output one resultset per batch. Here is a slightly modified query that works fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/1217

Comment: @AaronBertrand I just realize I cant do two `SELECT` using the @variable. The second `SELECT` was just for debug, the idea was use the @variable twice. But as you mention cant be done.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I believe credit solely goes to Aaron for pointing you out in the right direction.

Comment: You also have the credit. I more visual type person. I didnt understand the problem until saw the fiddle running. I wasnt uderstanding what `USING GO` mean.

Comment: I am glad that you found your answer! I learn new thing everyday here at SO.